# Catching connection error in Autobahn Component

Tags: python, python-asyncio, autobahn

I'm using Autobahn Python to connect to a Crossbar router. I'm hoping to handle the case where the crossbar router isn't available on the network. When using a class based Component I'm able to handle connection error however when using the functional Component I'm not able to capture and handle these exceptions.

```py
from autobahn.asyncio.component import Component

component = Component(transports="no_existent_url:3000",
                          realm=realm, authentication=authentication)

component.on('join', onJoinHandler)
# Called on exception when connected
component.on('leave', onLeaveHandler)
# Never called
component.on('connectfailure', onFailureHandler)
# Never called
component.on('disconnect', onDisconnectHandler)

component.start()
```

The errors are present in the console output:

```
Error in connection Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('no_existent_url', 3000), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
Connection failed: OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('no_existent_url', 3000), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
Component failed: Exhausted all transport connect attempts
```

Comment: Have you tried [using try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)?

Comment: @ExtraFishness Yes, the exception isn't thrown in the main run-loop so a try/except doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`Component.start()` returns a future which resolves when the component is either done or exits ([source code in component.py](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/a35f22eeaafca7568f1deb35c4a1b82ae78f77d4/autobahn/wamp/component.py#L535)). Awaiting this future and checking the `.exception()` method allows you to catch the exception.

```py
from autobahn.asyncio.component import Component

component = Component(transports="no_existent_url:3000",
                          realm=realm, authentication=authentication)

component.on('join', onJoinHandler)
# Called on exception when connected
component.on('leave', onLeaveHandler)
# Never called
component.on('connectfailure', onFailureHandler)
# Never called
component.on('disconnect', onDisconnectHandler)

future = component.start()

result = await future
if result.exception() is not None:
  # Handler exception
```